# Can convolutional network learn structural properties of one feature w.r.t to other?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, feature-selection, computer-vision, convolution

I'm going through the literature on pose-estimation ( DeeperCut, OpenPose, MultiPersonPosetrack).
I'm interested in knowing whether these networks/ generally a CNN can learn properties (geometrical) like opposites, same side, diagonal etc of one feature w.r.t the other features or is it based on closest neighborhood of that feature. For example, say a CNN trained on human joints be able to predict more accurately that left and right shoulders always on the same plane/straight line, left ear is closer to left eye that it is closer to the right eye.